# Cannot log into windows 10 pro with static IP address and no internet access

Tags: windows, login, windows-10, windows-authentication

I recently purchased a computer for a project at work. The OS is Windows 10 Pro. The computer asked for my Microsoft account while I was setting it up for the first time. I thought this was weird but I obediently provided my information, logged into the computer, and began configuring it to interface with another device on a different sub-net without internet access. I left for vacation and a week later I returned to the computer to pick up where I left off. In that time span the computer logged me off. In normal circumstances this would not present an issue. However, I was not able to log into the computer because it does not have internet access and therefore cannot authenticate my login. I have come to understand that the internet is required for me to log in because I did not set some obscure 'local log-in' setting while I able to use the computer. Does anybody have any experience with this issue or can anybody in the SO community provide guidance on how can I regain access to the computer? Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Not what youre askin for, but you could take a router and change the lan setings to match the static ip you have put on your comouter, so this router can route your trafic to Internett. Might not work if you didnt configure any dns setting on your computer.

Comment: The problem is that there are other people that are using the network therefore I cannot commandeer the router to do this.